# Are all cloaking devices in the MCU based on the same principles?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, cloaking

Several factions in the MCU seem to have access to vehicular cloaking devices. For example, they include at least:

- S.H.I.E.L.D. (Helicarrier in Avengers 2012)
- Avengers (Stark's cargo aircraft in Spider-Man: Homecoming)
- Wakanda (various air vehicles in Black Panther)
- Dark Elves (invasion fleet in Thor: The Dark World)

Do all cloaking devices in the MCU depend on the same technological and/or magical principles (to the extent, if any, that technology and magic can be considered distinct in the MCU)? If so, what are they? If not, how many different types of cloaking tech exist in the MCU?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are all completely separate technologies.

We see in Spider-Man: Homecoming that the stealth tech used by Stark cargo aircraft is some kind of active camouflage (with an LED projection of the world behind the aircraft), however we see in Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D. that S.H.I.E.L.D. cloaking tech is based on meta-materials. Neither of these methods would be able to fool Heimdall as the Dark Elves did, so Dark Elf tech must be something else. It seems that Wakanda's tech is some kind of hologram pseudoscience (judging from how they hide Wakanda). That is, I believe, all of the cloaking we've seen in the MCU thus far.

If you take the view that Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D. isn't canon, then it's possible but unlikely that SHIELD and Stark tech are the same.

Comment: Nice answer. I would have guessed that SHIELD's cloaking was (Howard?) Stark technology.

Comment: Don't forget the Inhumans' cloaked former-city Atillan on the moon.